# PHP Trying To Count Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to cut straight to the code.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("
SELECT *, COUNT(1) AS `numberofenteries1` FROM `table1` WHERE `user`='$username' GROUP BY `firstname`,`lastname`
");
$query2 = mysql_query("
SELECT *, COUNT(1) AS `numberofenteries2` FROM `table2` WHERE `user`='$username' GROUP BY `firstname`,`lastname`
");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
{
    $firstname  = $row ['firstname'];
    $lastname   = $row ['lastname'];
    $enteries1  = $row ['numberofenteries1'];
    $enteries2  = $row ['numberofenteries2'];
echo $enteries1 $enteries2;
```

I am trying to echo out two numbers counting rows from different table in a while loop. No matter what I try, I always run into an error. I have already tried naming the rows different, adding another row (row1 and row2) count to the while loop, and nothing. (For the code, it is necessary that I have them grabbing data from two different tables instead of one) How would I accomplish what I am aiming for. Any extra information will be provided. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the while bucle you have only the var $query1, that mind the count only return

```
$row ['numberofenteries1'];
```

---

try use this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1))
{
    $firstname  = $row ['firstname'];
    $lastname   = $row ['lastname'];
    $enteries1  = $row ['numberofenteries1'];
}


while($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
        $firstname2  = $rowa ['firstname'];
        $lastname2   = $rowa ['lastname'];
        $enteries2  = $rowa ['numberofenteries1'];
    }
```